# Python 3 socket int does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I recently came across little troubles with python variables affectations. I affected the same variable with different types. For instance:

```
hello = 1
print(hello)
hello = "Hello"
print(hello)
```

The output is what I expect: it displays `1` and then `hello`.

But I have a problem with an echo server test script:

```
skt_o = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
skt_o.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
skt_o.bind(('', 7777))
skt_o.listen(1)
lst_skt = []

while(1):
    lst, _, _ = select.select(lst_skt+[skt_o], [], [])

    for s in lst:
        if(s == skt_o):
            skt, _ = s.accept()
            lst_skt.append(skt)
        else:
            res = s.recv(1500)

            if(len(dat) == 0):
                print("[R-Close] %s" % s)
                s.close()
                lst_skt.remove(s)
                break

            for c in lst_skt:
                if(c !=  s):
                    res = c.send(res)
```

I use `nc localhost 7777` for connecting two terminals to the listening port. When I send a message everything work as expected. The two terminals can communicate. But when I launch a third terminal and try to send a message, I get a `TypeError` (int does not support the buffer interface).

if I replace the `res` variable as shown below everything work well. I can connect three and more terminals which can communicate:

```
dat = s.recv(1500)

if(len(dat) == 0):
    print("[R-Close] %s" % s)
    s.close()
    lst_skt.remove(s)
    break

    for c in lst_skt:
        if(c !=  s):
        res = c.send(dat)
```

What is the problem with the first echo script?

I know that the problem comes from this line:

```
res = c.send(res)
```

But I cannot explain why.

nb: I use Python 3.4.2

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I doubt the errors are "random". What errors are you talking about?

Comment: You still haven't said what the error is.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce it don't remember the exact sentence but the compiler claimed that he could not affect the variable with a new type.

Comment: It was a TypeError when using sockets. I will post the code tonight, need to go to work. @Carcigenicate I doubt the errors are "random". Me too I may have made a mistake. Well, we will see tonight.

Comment: If it was a TypeError it's likely you were doing something like `result = ''; result += sock.read(2048)`. Don't do that. BADTIE - **b**ytes **a**re **d**ecode, **t**ext **i**s **e**ncoded. Or it may be something else, given that you don't know what the error actually is.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in python 3.4.x the send method of the socket object accepts a '***byte***' sequence type as an argument. Thus you need to convert the argument you are passing to a byte by using a ***'b' prefix*** with normal string syntax: `b'python'`. This converts the string `python` to a byte sequence type. 
So in your code you need to convert the res you are passing into the send method to a byte.
Use something like this in your code instead. `res = c.send(b'some-string-or-integer')`
check the python docs on built-in types, **section 5.6** via the link below:
https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html

Also from the python docs too....

> Also, while in previous Python versions, byte strings and Unicode
>   strings could be exchanged for each other rather freely (barring
>   encoding issues), strings and bytes are now completely separate
>   concepts. There’s no implicit en-/decoding if you pass an object of
>   the wrong type. A string always compares unequal to a bytes or
>   bytearray object.